# What version of OpenGL is closest to OpenGL ES2?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I've been trying to work with OpenGL ES 2 in Android for some time now, but I'm finding the lack of experience with OpenGL itself to be an issue, since I barely understand what all the `GLES20` methods actually do. I've decided to try to learn actual OpenGL, but a little bit of reading has informed me that each version of OpenGL is drastically different from its predecessor. Wikipedia isn't very clear on which version that OpenGL ES2 most closely resembles.

So, my question is, which version of OpenGL should I learn for the purpose of better understanding OpenGL ES2?

Comment: "*a little bit of reading has informed me that each version of OpenGL is drastically different from its predecessor.*" This is not true at all. The closest this gets to being true is with [the core/compatibility divide](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts) at GL 3.1, but that's about it. Most GL versions are pretty incremental changes over the prior ones.

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 is decremental to GL 3.1. Most of the API is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0’s closest relative is OpenGL 2.0. Khronos provides a [difference specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_cm_spec_2.0.25.pdf), which enumerates what desktop OpenGL functionality was removed to create OpenGL 2.0. The shading language for OpenGL ES 2.0 (GLSL ES 1.0) is derived from GLSL 1.20.

Answer (score 1):

According to the book **OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide**:

> The OpenGL ES 1.0 and 1.1 specifications implement a fixed function
>   pipeline and are derived from the OpenGL 1.3 and 1.5 specifications,
>   respectively. **The OpenGL ES 2.0 specification** implements a
>   programmable graphics pipeline and **is derived from the OpenGL 2.0
>   specification**.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES2.0 is almost one-to-one copy of WebGL.

The differences are practically only in the setup of the environment, which in Android happens with EGL and which happens in WebGL with calls to DOM methods. (setting canvas)

The comparison to "open gl" is next to impossible, as Open GL means almost fixed and hidden rendering pipeline, which is controlled by stack of matrices and attributes. This is now obsoleted in ES. Instead one has the "opportunity" to control almost every aspect of the rendering pipeline.

Comment: -1: WebGL is not a *version of OpenGL*. Therefore it cannot be the closest version of OpenGL to GL ES 2.0.

Comment: Being able to write custom shaders (and actually understanding what they do, instead of just copy-pasting them from tutorials) is still necessary for OpenGL ES2, and do correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm assuming that learning OpenGL will help with this.

Comment: It would be pointless to deny that learning something didn't help learning some other thing. But in this case I wouldn't go through any version of open gl, but understanding matrices/hierachical systems, normals, coordinate systems, color models, splitting models to polygons and understanding shading models. Luckily the fixed pipeline performs still the vertex-to-scanline conversion and clipping. Any decent Computer Graphics book discusses these on a general level, which is closer to ES2.0 than the fixed pipeline and stack model.